# Problemas no JSONObject no Android

Tags: java, android, json, android-studio, getjson

Olá, pessoal ! Estou com uma dúvida relacionada ao JSON, é a primeira vez que estou mexendo com JSON no Android e estou com várias dúvidas, mas eu vi um tutorial no YouTube e consegui montar essa função

```
private void jsonParse(String url) {
    JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
            try {
                JSONArray jsonArray = response.getJSONArray("nome");

                for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject nome = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    String name = nome.getString("nome");

                    razao.append(name);
                    razao.setText(name);
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "CNPJ Inválido ! ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError erro) {
            erro.printStackTrace();
        }
    });

    mQueue.add(request);
}
```

Eu sei que em .getJSONArray(nome do JSON), mas o WebService que me retorna as informações não tem nome para percorrer um Array, preciso do "nome:" e ele está sozinho. Poderiam me ajudar ?

**Retorno do Android Studio:**

W/System.err: org.json.JSONException: Value GOOGLE BRASIL INTERNET LTDA. at nome of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONArray

**JSON**

{
"atividade_principal": [
{
"text": "Portais, provedores de conteúdo e outros serviços de informação na internet",
"code": "63.19-4-00"
}
],

"data_situacao": "01/09/2004",

"complemento": "ANDAR 17A20 TSUL 2 17A20",
"tipo": "MATRIZ",

**"nome": "GOOGLE BRASIL INTERNET LTDA."**,

"uf": "SP",

"telefone": "(11) 2395-8400",

"email": "googlebrasil@google.com",

Link: https://www.receitaws.com.br/v1/cnpj/06990590000123

Comment: Se precisar de mais informações no código, podem pedir, por favor ! Realmente preciso de ajuda e não consigo me entender nessa parte

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aparentemente, você está tentando pegar a chave "nome", que não é um array/lista, e transformar em um objeto JSONArray. Isso é um problema porque a função não vai conseguir converter uma string em um objeto JSONArray. Acredito que você poderia usar simplesmente getString("nome"). A chave "qsa" sim é um array e você poderia utilizar getJSONArray("qsa") para iterar e obter a chave nome de cada objeto desse array.

Espero ter entendido direito seu problema, porque confesso que não sou experiente em Java. rsrs

Comment: Obrigado ! Não sabia dessa parte ! Mas ele continua dando erro de conversão de String.

public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                try {
                    JSONObject jsonObject = response.getJSONObject("nome");
                    jsonObject.toString();

                    razao.append(jsonObject.toString());
                    razao.setText(jsonObject.toString());

W/System.err: org.json.JSONException: Value GOOGLE BRASIL INTERNET LTDA. at nome of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject